# Generic reverse of list items in Python

Tags: python, sequences

```
>>> b=[('spam',0), ('eggs',1)]
>>> [reversed(x) for x in b]
[<reversed object at 0x7fbf07de7090>, <reversed object at 0x7fbf07de70d0>]
```

Bummer. I expected to get a list of reversed tuples!

Sure I can do:

```
>>> [tuple(reversed(x)) for x in b]
[(0, 'spam'), (1, 'eggs')]
```

But I hoped for something generic? Smth that when being handed over a list of tuples, returns a list of reversed tuples, and when handed over a list of lists, returns a list of reversed lists.

Sure, an ugly hack with isinstance() is always available but I kind of hoped avoiding going that route.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Extended slicing](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

```
[x[::-1] for x in b]
```

Comment: linky link for more info: http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html

Answer (score 0):

If you only need depth of one, try [x[::-1] for x in mylist]. Otherwise just make a recursive function like

```
import collections
def recursive_reversed(seq):
    if isinstance(seq, collections.Sequence):
        return [recursive_reversed(x) for x in reversed(seq)]
    return seq
```

That function actually converts all of the sequences to lists, but you get the gist, I hope.